# How does one repeat the same Google ad slot on the same page?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, drupal

I would like to repeat the same ad on a page, appearing every few rows as the user scrolls through a list of articles.

On that site there are two ad slots (rail1 and rail3) that appear multiple times as the user scrolls.   I'd like this same effect on my site where I can show multiple ads on the same page, without the need to create so many ad slots.

My site is on Drupal 9, and I use the DFP module to create ad slots.  I have tried several ways of rendering the ads, such as rendering this code throughout the page:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.display('js-dfp-tag-boombox3');
});
```

I can render an ad successfully once like this.  I have tried to program the page to repeat every few rows by removing the first ad and re-inserting this code again.  I have also tried programming the page to move the ad div to a new spot.  But after appearing initially on page load, the ad never appears again when I re-render or move it.

Since I can see other sites do this, I'm wondering what the trick is.  Thanks.